# Простая функция на Haskell

Tags: haskell

Есть функция на Haskell

```
 filterGr :: QuestStat -> QuestStat
 filterGr ((q,s,d):xs) = fgHlp s ((q,s,d):xs) 
      where fgHlp maxS = filter (\(q,s,d) -> s == maxS)
```

У меня вопрос: необходимо ли писать `fgHlp s ((q,s,d):xs)` или можно `fgHlp s`. Что дает запись с `((q,s,d):xs)`?

И еще возник вопрос: функция `filter` получает предикат и список, а в приведенной функции только предикат?! Или я неправ?

P.S. Если что `QuestStat` - список: `[( String, Integer, Integer)]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Хаскелле имеется возможность писать функции в так называемом бесточечном (pointfree) стиле:

```
sum  :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
sum  =  foldl (+) 0
```

При этом мы не указываем аргумент функции (точку её применения, отсюда термин бесточечный), но должны сделать это как справа, так и слева от знака `=` в определении функции. В данном примере из стандартной библиотеки опущен суммируемый список, "полное" определение выглядело бы так

```
sum  :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
sum xs  =  foldl (+) 0 xs
```

В вашем примере бесточечным образом определена вспомогательная функция `fgHlp`, можно было бы определить её и так

```
fgHlp maxS ys  =  filter (\(q,s,d) -> s == maxS) ys
```

Здесь `filter` принимает "правильное" число аргументов - предикат и список, однако в Хаскелле применение функции к меньшему числу аргументов, чем у неё предполагается тоже допустимо.

Что касается первого вопроса, то технически написать справа в определении `filterGr` выражение `fgHlp s` было бы можно, если бы нам не нужно было извлекать `s` из головы списка в левой части этого определения. То есть записав бесточечно:

```
filterGr  =  fgHlp s
```

мы бы столкнулись с проблемой: что здесь такое `s`?